# define this map-reduce function(UDF) in hive

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I have a hive table A with 4 **string** columns with name: user, item, type, time

The sample input is as follows:

```
user  item  type   time
1     101    0     06-16   # June 16, 2013 , all dates are in the same year 
2     101    0     09-04
1     102    1     07-03
```

There are 4 types (0,1,2,3), with weights(1,2,3,4, respectively). There is a time score for each row defined as follows:
`tScore = (time - 06-01-2013)/7`
i.e, how many weeks from June 1st
`fScore = weight of type * time score`
then I need to aggregate fScore based on (user,item) as the key and sort the table according to descending aggregated fScore.

I don't know if I described what I am trying to do clearly. Please comment if anything unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user, item, (type + 1) * datediff(concat('2013-', time), '2013-06-01') / 7 as fScore
from A
order by fScore desc;
```

Check out https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF for all of the built-in functions.

Also, if it's not the case that the weight is just (type + 1), you could replace that part with a case statement. For example:

```
select user, item, case type when 0 then 1 when 1 then 2 when 2 then 3...
```